# How to change code example font in listings?

Tags: fonts, listings

Does anyone know how to change the font for code snippets in the `listings` package? I'd like to have a constant width font, rather the fancy variable-width looking font that it has by default.

Comment: Please read the manual first. It took me less than ten seconds to find the answer via google.

Comment: @PeterisKrumins Thank for asking the question here.  I too was looking for this information, and searched for `font` as you did.  I have the listings package PDF, I did a 15-minute search of the 58-page document, and the answer was not obvious to me.  I needed the answer faster than having to read 58 pages first (just to change a font).  Google led me to StackExchange and this page and the answer right away.  Thank you for saving me time.

Answer (score 15):

As shown at page 28 of the manual, adding the option

```
basicstyle=\ttfamily
```

to the `\lstset{}` command would make what you ask.
Keep in mind to always read the packages documentation on your machine before posting.

Comment: I find `basicstyle=\footnotesize\ttfamily` even better for the default LaTeX layout.

Comment: http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/33685/set-the-font-family-for-lstlisting

Comment: Keep an open mind: Peteris Krumins maybe tried to read the documentation and found it incomprehensible. Actually, that's why I'm here. +1 for *your* answer.