# How to emphasize the character '&' within a listing?

Tags: listings, highlighting

How do I emphasize with the `listings` package the column separators in a tabular environment?
This is my MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{lmodern}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{array,longtable,tabularx,ctable}
\usepackage{siunitx}
\usepackage{listings}
\lstset{
   language={[LaTeX]tex},
   basicstyle=\ttfamily,
   keywordstyle=\color{blue}\bfseries,
   stringstyle=\color{red},
   commentstyle=\color{green},
   columns=fullflexible,
   %
   morekeywords={tabular,toprule,midrule,bottomrule},
   otherkeywords={},
   emph={},
   emphstyle={\color{red}\bfseries}
}
\begin{document}
This is my tabular material:

\medskip

\begin{tabular}{lcl}
\toprule
2.3456   & 2.3456    & 0.1 \\
12,3456 & 12,3456  & 12,3456   \\
-9,8765  & -9,8765  & -9,8765   \\
\bottomrule
\end{tabular}

\medskip

And this is the code:

\medskip

\begin{lstlisting}
\begin{tabular}{lcl}
\toprule
2.3456   & 2.3456    & 0.1 \\
12,3456 & 12,3456  & 12,3456   \\
-9,8765  & -9,8765  & -9,8765   \\
\bottomrule
\end{tabular}
\end{lstlisting}

\end{document}
```

How can the character `&` have a separated emphasizing style?
TYIA.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Having

```
   otherkeywords={\&},
   emph={&},
   emphstyle={\color{red}\bfseries}
```

in the `lstset` works for this example, but the `listings` manual warns against it, IIUC:

> One final hint: Keep the lists of identifiers disjoint. Never use a
>   keyword in an ‘emphasize’ list or one name in two different lists.
>   Even if your source code is highlighted as expected, there is no
>   guarantee that it is still the case if you change the order of your
>   listings or if you use the next release of this package.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{lmodern}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{array,longtable,tabularx,ctable}
\usepackage{siunitx}
\usepackage{listings}
\lstset{
   language={[LaTeX]tex},
   basicstyle=\ttfamily,
   keywordstyle=\color{blue}\bfseries,
   stringstyle=\color{red},
   commentstyle=\color{green},
   columns=fullflexible,
   %
   morekeywords={,tabular,toprule,midrule,bottomrule},
   otherkeywords={\&},
   emph={&},
   emphstyle={\color{red}\bfseries}
}
\begin{document}
This is my tabular material:

\medskip

\begin{tabular}{lcl}
\toprule
2.3456   & 2.3456    & 0.1 \\
12,3456 & 12,3456  & 12,3456   \\
-9,8765  & -9,8765  & -9,8765   \\
\bottomrule
\end{tabular}

\medskip

And this is the code:

\medskip

\begin{lstlisting}
\begin{tabular}{lcl}
\toprule
2.3456   & 2.3456    & 0.1 \\
12,3456 & 12,3456  & 12,3456   \\
-9,8765  & -9,8765  & -9,8765   \\
\bottomrule
\end{tabular}
\end{lstlisting}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 3):

The other solution addresses your specific question, but I would highly recommend that you consider using [the `showexpl` pacakge](http://ctan.org/tex-archive/macros/latex/contrib/showexpl) which makes use of the `listings` package.   This eliminates the duplication of the LaTeX code, so it is not as error prone.

[image]

### Note:

- A fix from [Fixed Width Font with LTXexample environment](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/17646/fixed-width-font-with-ltxexample-environment) is applied here.

### Code:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{ctable}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{showexpl}% includes listings

% https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/17646/fixed-width-font-with-ltxexample-environment
\sbox0{\small\ttfamily A}
\edef\mybasewidth{\the\wd0 }

\lstdefinestyle{demoLatexStyle}{
    basicstyle=\ttfamily,% control font of code
    preset=\small,% adjust font size of output
    numbers=left, numberstyle=\tiny, stepnumber=2, numbersep=5pt,
    frame=tlbr,
    rframe={},% no frame around the output
    pos=r,% output on right
    backgroundcolor=\color{yellow!30},
    width=0.45\linewidth,
    keywordstyle=\color{blue}\bfseries,
    stringstyle=\color{red},
    commentstyle=\color{green},
    columns=fixed,basewidth=\mybasewidth,
    morekeywords={,tabular,toprule,midrule,bottomrule},
    otherkeywords={\&},
    emph={&},
    emphstyle={\color{red}\bfseries}
}
\lstloadlanguages{[LaTeX]TeX}

\begin{document}
\noindent
This is my tabular material and the associated code:
\medskip
\begin{LTXexample}[style=demoLatexStyle]
\begin{tabular}{lcl}
\toprule
2.3456   & 2.3456   & 0.1     \\
12,3456  & 12,3456  & 12,3456 \\
-9,8765  & -9,8765  & -9,8765 \\
\bottomrule
\end{tabular}
\end{LTXexample}
\end{document}
```