# Changing font in listings-package

Tags: listings

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [set the font family for lstlisting](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/33685/set-the-font-family-for-lstlisting)

I need to change the font while using the listings-package since my TeX template seems to interfere with standard listings settings (the code text appears in some calligraphic font which looks really stupid for source code). 
I already tried using `basicstyle=\ttfamily` as an option, but this only changes the character spaces. Is there a way to completely switch the font to e.g. Courier?

Any help appreciated, I couldn't find anything on this in the package manual or google...

EDIT: The link from Peter Grill ( [set the font family for lstlisting](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/33685/set-the-font-family-for-lstlisting/) ) solved my problem, thanks a lot! (And sorry for the duplicate!)

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! Would you please add a minimal example of the code you have up to now?

Comment: here is an example: http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/60294/latex-verbatim-source-code-beside-the-typeset-output/61273#61273

Comment: Possible Duplicate: [set the font family for lstlisting](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/33685/set-the-font-family-for-lstlisting/).  Related Question: [Fixed Width Font with LTXexample environment](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/17646/fixed-width-font-with-ltxexample-environment).

Comment: As I see it, this is more of a font-changing issue than a `listings` one. If you only need the typewriter font for code, try writing `\def\ttfamily{lmtt}` OR `\usepackage{courier}` in the preamble, and then `\basicstyle=\ttfamily` in your `listings` settings. Or show us a minimal example, please. Note that if your code is in italics, Computer Modern or Latin Modern (the default fonts) are much more "calligraphic" than Courier or other mono fonts.