# Spacing looks wrong in listings when using fixed columns

Tags: listings, kerning

When I use `columns=fixed` to present my listings, the letters are spaced too far apart. Why is that?

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{listings}
\lstset{columns=fixed, basicstyle=\ttfamily}}

\begin{document}
\begin{lstlisting}
Hello, world!
\end{lstlisting}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The problem, as user egreg has previously pointed out, is that

> the default setting of listings with "fixed columns" has a space 0.6em wide, while the characters in Computer Modern Typewriter are 0.5em wide.
>   [Fixed Width Font with LTXexample environment](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/17651/25356)

One can use the `basewidth` key to fix this.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{listings}
\lstset{columns=fixed, basicstyle=\ttfamily, basewidth=0.5em}

\begin{document}
\begin{lstlisting}
Hello, world!
\end{lstlisting}
\end{document}
```

[image]

The answer linked above also provides a more flexible solution that works regardless of which monospaced font you use.