# Put colored text inside a lstlisting

Tags: color, listings, typewriter

So I've been looking for a way to color text inside a lstlisting. There are already several questions answere. E.g. here: [How can I highlight some lines from source code?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/8851/how-can-i-highlight-some-lines-from-source-code/8860#8860?newreg=7663bc4bb2d14151a1044a36ea2e328d)

All solutions I've found have the same approach. Just use an escape character and colour the text. However, if I do this my font is not monospace anymore. Is there a way to fix this? Neither setting font to `\ttfamily` or using `\verb`/`\texttt` did work.

Here is an example of what's going wrong:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{listings,xcolor}

\begin{document}

\begin{lstlisting}[escapeinside={(*@}{@*)}, basicstyle=\tiny\ttfamily]
this is monospace
as you can see here
(*@\color{orange}not monospace anymore@*) 
\end{lstlisting}

\end{document}
```

Cheers
Pascal

Comment: The `listings` manual says (section 5.12): _Note: Any escape to LaTeX may disturb the column alignment since the package can’t control the spacing there._ so probably there is no easy solution.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE by the way!

Comment: But if you are willing to make the `listings` font a bit more narrow (while it still remains monospaced, i.e., every character and space has the same width) you can do something like `\begin{lstlisting}[escapeinside={(*@}{@*)},basicstyle=\tiny\ttfamily,columns=fixed,basewidth=.5em]` as in https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/17646/fixed-width-font-with-ltxexample-environment/.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can get around the problem with `\aftergroup`.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{listings,xcolor}

\def\speciallstcolor{\begingroup\color{orange}}
\def\endspeciallstcolor{\endgroup}

\begin{document}

\begin{lstlisting}[escapeinside={(*@}{@*)}, basicstyle=\tiny\ttfamily]
this is monospace
as you can see here
(*@\aftergroup\speciallstcolor@*)not monospace anymore(*@\aftergroup\endspeciallstcolor@*)
(that was a lie)
\end{lstlisting}

\end{document}
```

[image: MWE output]