# set the font family for lstlisting

Tags: fonts, listings, formatting

I have the following set up for my listings :

```
\lstset{basicstyle=\footnotesize,breaklines=true}
\lstset{framextopmargin=50pt,frame=bottomline}
```

I would like to change the font family to `Courier`. How can I enable this?

Comment: Why not just use a monospaced font like `\ttfamily` (from Computer Modern)?

Comment: @Werner I am sorry but I am not following you here. You might have got that I am newbie :s

Comment: It is recommendable to take a look at Section 4.6 of the [listings](http://ctan.org/pkg/listings) manual.

Comment: @tugberk: See @Peter's answer. `basicstyle=\ttfamily` prints the listing content using `\ttfamily` - a monospaced font.

Comment: @Werner what does ttfamily actually do here? To me, just a miracle happen there. I didn't say the you can use the courier. I just put the ttfamily there.

Comment: @tugberk: `\ttfamily` is a Computer Modern font which looks very similar to Adobe's Courier. Adding `\usepackage{courier}` overrides the `\ttfamily` output to now represent Courier. If the similarities are negligible to you, just use `\ttfamily`. It's that simple.

Comment: @Werner aha, ttfamily is a font family. I thought that was a command. thanks for the clarification.

Comment: @tugberk: You can use `\texttt{...}` or `{\ttfamily ...}` which produces the same result.

Answer (score 84, accepted):

With `\usepackage{courier}` in your preamble you can use the courier font in the listings as follows:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{listings}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{courier}

\lstset{basicstyle=\footnotesize\ttfamily,breaklines=true}
\lstset{framextopmargin=50pt,frame=bottomline}

\begin{document}
\begin{lstlisting}
   a b c
\end{lstlisting}
\lipsum[1]
\end{document}
```

The `\usepackage{courier}` in the preamble causes `\ttfamily` to produce output in the courier font.  Without including this package, you can still use `\ttfamily` to get a mono spaced font by including that as part of the `basicstyle=...` setting.

Comment: Wouldn't this solution affect the fonts of the entire document? Or am I missing something?

Comment: @AdrianKeister: Did you try running the MWE?

Comment: @AdrianKeister this is not the case.

Answer (score 59):

Modify your basicstyle to include the font family:

```
\lstset{basicstyle=\ttfamily\footnotesize,breaklines=true}
```

Comment: This proved to be a far better answer as it does not impact the whole document.

Answer (score 2):

If you use `\lstset{basicstyle=\fontfamily{pcr}\footnotesize}` it will set only the font used in listings to Courier. Original response where this snippet was found is [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/34363). A list containing some of the supported fonts can be found [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/378626).

Comment: Warning: `\fontfamily` **should** be followed by `\selectfont`, in this case it just happen to work because it's followed by `\footnotesize` -- in particular if you swap the 2 commands it will not work anymore.