# Artifacts from Latex configuration showing in output

Tags: pdf, miktex, output

I've written some Latex in my doxygen comment that looks like this...

```
/*!
@note
@latexonly

\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{courier}

\lstset{basicstyle=\footnotesize\ttfamily}

\begin{document}
\fontsize{10pt}{12pt}\selectfont
\newpage
\begin{verbatim}
```

CONTENT

```
\end{verbatim}
\end{document}
@endlatexonly
*/
```

Produces this after running 'pdflatex'

```
article courier
basicstyle=
(PageBreak: No text in PDF) 
CONTENT
```

What am I doing wrong? I just wanted to set the text to a monospace font and have it output verbatim.

Note: I'm running MikTeX 2.9 on windows 7

### Update:

I Took a look in the .tex file doxygen makes for the class with this comment and found this.

```
 \begin{DoxyNote}{Note}
```

//Everything above

```
\end{DoxyNote}
```

Could that create the odd things I'm seeing?

### Update 2:

I found [this](http://www.doxygen.nl/manual/commands.html#cmdlatexonly),

> Starts a block of text that will be verbatim included in the generated
>   LaTeX documentation only.

So that tells me MiKTeX doesn't like those labels. When doxygen creates the .Tex files this bit shows up in the middle. Does LaTeX have rules about defining a preamble in the middle of a document? This is the first thing I've ever done in LaTeX so I'm not surprised that I'm having issues.

I did some testing and when I remove `\documentclass`,`\begin{document}` and `\end{document}` it didn't get rid of the artifacts but it did fix some other problems I opened [another question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/127940/34837) about funny enough. And then moved to [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/18219617/839501)

Comment: Can't help with `Doxygen`, but doesn't the command `\lstset` require you to load something like the `listings` package (i.e., `\usepackage{listings}`)?

Comment: I honestly couldn't tell you I adapted an example from [here](http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/33686/34837). 
I am using `\usepackage{courier}` right before that line. And from what the link mentioned that was so `ttfamily` could use it.

Comment: @jon oh you're right it's for setting listings to courier. Could you tell me how to set the content section to courier correctly then?

Comment: It (a normal LaTeX document) should work as long as you add the line `\usepackage{listings}`.  The fontsize can more easily be set to 10pt by loading it as an option to your documentclass: `\documentclass[10pt]{article}`.  ... But how that all interacts/works with `Doxygen` is not something I can competently answer.

Comment: @jon now I'm getting `article
listings courier
basicstyle=` :p. I get the feeling this might be Doxygen but lets not count out my noob-ness either. Thanks for trying to help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### EUREKA!

The labels you add in Doxygen comments are inside a `\begin{document}` or something like it. So preamble (I think that's what definitions like `\usepackage` are called) aren't valid syntax there.

So what was happening was the `\COMMANDS` would be absorbed, deemed invalid there and the arguments would come through as plain text.

So the answer was to this is...

```
/*!
@note
@latexonly
\newpage
\fontsize{10pt}{12pt}\selectfont    
\ttfamily
\begin{verbatim}
```

CONTENT

```
\end{verbatim}    
@endlatexonly
*/
```

Strictly speaking all `\ttfamily` guarantees is a monospaced font but that's all I wanted.
:)