# Use Dev-C++ style to write code using listings package

Tags: color, code, sharelatex

I would like to write this piece of code using `listings` package:

[image: Dev-C++ style]

However I have some problems:

- I cannot set the grouper symbol;
- The `0` does not have the diagonal slash.

*The size of the code has to be `\scriptsize` or something like that.*

The MWE that I use is this [ShareLaTeX document](https://www.sharelatex.com/learn/Code_listing#Code_styles_and_colours).

Or is there any snippet created that copy the style of `Dev-C++`?

Thanks!

Comment: Are you searching for solutions only for pdfLaTeX or other engines too? With XeLaTeX/LuaLaTeX it's pretty easy to use a slashed zero in code listings and (if you want to) a non-slashed zero otherwise.

Comment: Unfortunately I use `pdfLaTeX`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Regarding the 0 with a diagonal slash: You have to use the right (monospace) font for that. The easiest options for this might be [Inconsolata](http://www.tug.dk/FontCatalogue/inconsolata/) or one of GoMono / TXTT / Anonymous Pro.

[This question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/33685/set-the-font-family-for-lstlisting) helps with how to set the font:
Just load the monopsace font after your normal font (if any) with `\usepackage{inconsolata}` and use `\lstset{basicstyle=\footnotesize\ttfamily}` to setup your listing. Of course, you can use `\scriptsize` instead of `\footnotesize` to make it even smaller.

Comment: Yes, your solution works! Btw: *1)* Is it possible to keep the same font of the `listings` package? (You see that I don't touch the `basicstyle` only for the size). *2)* I have indented my code using TAB, but now the output does not show this indentation. *3)* The are no more spaces between words. Do you know how to fix that or which link do you  recommend?

Comment: Great to hear! 1) To use the monospace font for the whole document use `\renewcommand*\familydefault{\ttdefault}` 2)/3) Try using `\lstset{keepspaces=true}` or search for questions like [this one](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/19949/how-to-make-listings-code-indentation-remain-unchanged-when-copied-from-pdf/19978)