# Can I change the font just for lstlisting?

Tags: listings

I'd like to keep all the fonts for the document the same and only change the font for the llstststing environment to something sensible like [IBM Plex mono](https://tug.org/FontCatalogue/ibmplexmonoregular/), [Adobe Source Code Pro](https://github.com/adobe-fonts/source-code-pro), or [Noto Sans Mono](https://fonts.google.com/noto/specimen/Noto+Sans+Mono). Is that possible and how so?

MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage{blindtext}
\usepackage{plex-mono}

\usepackage[table,xcdraw]{xcolor}
\definecolor{backcolour}{rgb}{0.98,0.98,0.95}

\usepackage{listings}
\lstdefinestyle{prettycode}{
    backgroundcolor=\color{backcolour},
    aboveskip={0.9\baselineskip},               
    keepspaces=true,
}
\lstset{style=prettycode}

\begin{document}
    \section{Section One}
    \blindtext

\begin{lstlisting}[language=c, caption=Hello world program., label=listing:hello_world]
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
    
    // prints hello world
    printf("Hello World");
    
    return 0;
}
\end{lstlisting}
\subsection{Subsection}
    \blindtext
\end{document}
```

Related, but solutions seem to change the typewriter font for the whole document: [set the font family for lstlisting](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/33685/set-the-font-family-for-lstlisting)

Comment: If you already have a font-switching command which can be defined by eg `fontspec`'s `\newfontfamily`, then `\lstset{basicstyle=<cmd>}` will do the work.

Comment: switching from pdflatex to xelatex is messing with all the fonts of the document. I absolutely need fontspec?

Comment: As the fonts you mentioned are all otf/ttf fonts, yes (unless you want to directly use `\font` primitive).

Comment: Where can I learn more about this `/font` primitive?

Comment: The [_XeTeX Reference_](https://ctan.org/pkg/xetex) and the [_LuaTeX Reference_](https://ctan.org/pkg/luatex). `fontspec` is more or less just a wrapper to (different) font selection primitives and syntaxes provided by xetex and luatex, and it provides an cross-engine, easier-to-use, easier-to-read interface. Why you want to avoid it so much?

Comment: Because it's not a fresh document, it is a template and once I change it from pdflatex to xelatex or lualatex all the fonts of the document are changed.

Comment: Then the problem is not about `fontspec` at all, but about changing engine from pdftex to xe- or lua-tex, right? LaTeX uses `TU` font encoding for unicode engines, but `T1` for pdftex. This may cause font messing. If the font you want is accessible under pdftex, then it's always possible to define a font switching command and use it in `basicstyle=<cmd>`. Among the fonts you mentioned, both [plex](ctan.org/pkg/plex) and [noto](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/noto) have pdftex support. If you've decided which font to use and have trouble applying it only for `lstlisting`, welcome back.

Comment: I've added an mwe. How canI change the font without switching to luatex or xetex?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'd not use different monospaced fonts for different parts of one and the same  document.

However, you can do what you want, provided you delve a bit into the font packages.

###### IBM Plex Mono

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[table,xcdraw]{xcolor}
\usepackage{listings}

\definecolor{backcolour}{rgb}{0.98,0.98,0.95}

\newcommand{\listingsttfamily}{\fontfamily{IBMPlexMono-TLF}\small}

\lstdefinestyle{prettycode}{
  basicstyle=\listingsttfamily,
  backgroundcolor=\color{backcolour},
  aboveskip={0.9\baselineskip},               
  keepspaces=true,
}
\lstset{style=prettycode}

\begin{document}

\section{Section One}

Some text with a \texttt{monospaced} insert.

\begin{lstlisting}[language=c, caption=Hello world program., label=listing:hello_world]
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
    
    // prints hello world
    printf("Hello World");
    
    return 0;
}
\end{lstlisting}

\end{document}
```

[image]

###### Source Code Pro

Replace the line for `\listingsttfamily` with

```
\newcommand{\listingsttfamily}{\fontfamily{SourceCodePro-TLF}\small}
```

[image]

###### Noto Sans Mono

Replace the line with

```
\newcommand{\listingsttfamily}{\fontfamily{NotoSansMono-TLF}\small}
```

but note that this has no italics nor slanted shapes.

[image]

Comment: I understand it's against typography common sense to use two different monospaced fonts in the same document, but this is a conference template I want to adhere to. At the same time it doesn't have any example for code display which I find hard to read in courier family font. Hence I don't want to touch the rest of the style, just the listing style. Thanks for the excellent solution.