# Custom verbatim that sets all spaces (" ") as visible spaces ("␣") that can line-break

Tags: spacing, macros, line-breaking, verbatim

It makes sense to typeset code in a monospaced font. Sometimes such code needs to be embedded in a paragraph context, and then it will be useful to allow it to linebreak. In order to visualize spaces properly, **I would like a macro `\code` that typesets its argument with all spaces replaced by visible spaces that can line-break (on both sides)**. For example, it'd typeset

```
\code{string with  spaces}
```

as `string␣with␣␣spaces` where each `␣` can linebreak on either side. As my question is about code that is to be embedded in paragraph text, we can assume that the argument to such a `\code` macro won't contain any paragraph breaks.

Actually my use case is more specific. I typeset string constants using the macro `\strC` shown below. This might still be interesting to others, as it is a bit more than just a variation on `\verb`, with the custom `\textsl` potentially complicating the solution.

I presently use an explicit call to a macro `\vsp` (simply defined as `\allowbreak\textvisiblespace\allowbreak`; both `\allowbreak`s are needed) as a workaround, but it would be nice to be able to just type (one or more) spaces inside the macro argument.

```
\documentclass{article}

\newcommand*{\strC}[1]{\textnormal{`\textsl{\texttt{#1}}'}} % string constant
\newcommand*{\vsp}{\allowbreak\textvisiblespace\allowbreak} % visible space

\begin{document}

\hspace*{31em}\strC{hello world}
% linebreaks as:  ‘hello / world’    (space disappears)

\hspace*{31em}\strC{hello\textvisiblespace{}world}
% linebreaks as:  ‘hello␣world’ / ∅  (no linebreak)

\hspace*{31em}\strC{hello\vsp{}world}
% linebreaks as:  ‘hello / ␣world’   (as intended; a linebreak after ␣ would also be ok)

\end{document}
```

For this code specifically the idea would be to type `\strC{hello world}` but to get the same result as with `\strC{hello\vsp{}world}`. Multiple typed spaces should yield multiple `␣`-characters; a string `␣␣␣␣␣` may break anywhere (beginning, anywhere in the middle, end).

[Here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/73717/14996) is a related question also asking about functional conversion of input (in this case for the specific purpose of pasting).

---

**Summary of answers:**
Both answers are very good, and the comment pair (just below) by user [cacamailg](https://tex.stackexchange.com/users/16720/) is very good too, but no solution as of the time of this edit is perfect. For now I'll stick with my manual `\vsp` macro, which is quick to type and gives me full control. If someone has a refinement of one of the three approaches that is flawless, I'll accept that as the answer.

Comment: The package `listings` has the `\lstinline` for inline and `lstlisting` environment. With the options: `\lstset{breaklines=true,showspaces=true}` probably does what you want.

Comment: @cacamailg Except for the styling of the font, it does! I haven't tried the customization options of `listings`, which might help with that.

Comment: For the font change see: http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/33685/set-the-font-family-for-lstlisting and http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/17009/how-to-change-code-example-font-in-listings.

Answer (score 6):

You have to change the meaning of the active space. (Of course this means that `\code` cannot be in the argument to another command (see below*), though careful usage of `\scantokens` might help.)

```
\documentclass{article}

\newcommand*{\strC}{\begingroup
  \obeyspaces
  \begingroup\lccode`~=`\ %
  \lowercase{\endgroup\let~}\vsp
  \dostrC}
\newcommand{\dostrC}[1]{\textnormal{`{\slshape\ttfamily#1}'}\endgroup} % string constant
\newcommand*{\vsp}{\allowbreak\textvisiblespace\allowbreak} % visible space

\begin{document}

\hspace*{31em}\strC{hello world  x   y}

\end{document}
```

[image]

---

*For example, if we wrap the command into a macro `\ident` that doesn't modify its argument (`\newcommand*{\ident}[1]{#1}`), the result of

```
\ident{\strC{hello world  x   y}}
```

turns out to be as if we had used the original `\strC` macro without any explicit visible spaces: all space sequences will be shrunk to an ordinary (i.e., line-breaking and disappearing ("soft")) space.

Comment: @LoverofStructure If you add `\scantokens{` before `\textnormal` and `\noexpand}` before the closing quote, you can use `\strC` in the argument to another command; but you can't get multiple spaces, because they are converted to single space tokens during tokenization and this can't be reverted.

Answer (score 3):

[EDITED to address multi-softspace issue] The `stringstrings` package might apply here, with a caveat.  Since stringstrings is not a verbatim like string processor, multiple spaces in an argument are otherwise interpreted by LaTeX as a single space token, unless you explicitly put hard spaces (~ characters) to represent multiple spaces.  So I tried a `\catcode` redefinition to try to overcome that limitation.  As long as the `\strC` invocation doesn't follow the starred version of `\hspace`, it seems to work (not sure what is peculiar to the star version, but in that situation, multi-softspaces are interpreted as a single softspace).  Thus, with that exception noted, `stringstrings` can parse the string, converting spaces and tildes, each into a visible space character, allowing line breaks.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{stringstrings}

\newcommand*{\strC}[1]{%
\catcode`\ =12%
\strCB{#1}%
\catcode`\ =13%
}

\newcommand*{\strCB}[1]{%
  \encodetoken[1]{\textvisiblespace}%
  \encodetoken[2]{\allowbreak}%
  \convertchar[e]{#1}{ }{\allowbreak\textvisiblespace\allowbreak}%
  \convertchar[e]{\thestring}{~}{\allowbreak\textvisiblespace\allowbreak}%
  \retokenize{\thestring}%
  \textnormal{`\textsl{\texttt{\thestring}}'}%
  \decodetoken[1]{\textvisiblespace}%
  \decodetoken[2]{\allowbreak}%
} % string constant

\begin{document}

The hspace* affects the bevavior of the subsequent strC (not sure why).

\hspace*{31em}\strC{hello world.  This is a ~ Big   test}

But in other cases, multiple softspaces are correctly interpreted:

\strC{Hello   World}

\strC{hello world.  This is a ~ Big   test}

\hspace{31em}\strC{hello world.  This is a ~ Big   test}

\end{document}
```

[image]

I would add some final disclaimers: stringstrings is slow, which can be a problem for large manipulations; stringstrings isn't made to easily handle the `\` backslash character.  This isn't a problem if the code you are typesetting is a language that doesn't use the backslash character, but will obviously be so if you are typesetting LaTeX code.